# Matlab: How to replace dynamic part of string with regexprep

Tags: regex, matlab

I have strings like

```
@(foo) 5 + foo.^2
@(bar) bar(1,:) + bar(4,:)
```

and want the expression in the first group of parentheses (which could be anything) to be replaced by `x` in the whole string

```
@(x) 5 + x.^2
@(x) x(1,:) + x(4,:)
```

I thought this would be possible with `regexprep` in one step somehow, but after reading the docu and fiddling around for quite a while, I have not found a working solution, yet.

I know, one could use two commands: First, grab the string to be matched with `regexp` and then use it with `regexprep` to replace all occurrences.

However, I have the gut feeling this should be somehow possible with the functionality of dynamic expressions and tokens or the like.

Comment: what happens if you have `'@(s) 5 + sum( s )'`? The basic replace would break the anonymous function leaving `'@(x) 5 + xum( x )'`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the support of an infinite-width lookbehind, you cannot do that in one step with a single call to `regexprep`.

Use the first idea: extract the first word and then replace it with `x` when found in between word boundaries:

```
s = '@(bar) bar(1,:) + bar(4,:)';
word = regexp(s, '^@\((\w+)\)','tokens'){1}{1};
s = regexprep(s, strcat('\<',word,'\>'), 'x');
```

Output: `@(x) x(1,:) + x(4,:)`

The `^@\((\w+)\)` regex matches the `@(` at the start of the string, then captures alphanumeric or `_` chars into Group 1 and then matches a `)`. `tokens` option allows accessing the captured substring, and then the `strcat('\<',word,'\>')` part builds the whole word matching regex for the `regexprep` command.

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I had aready in mind. In your second line, I maybe would have used `word = regexp(s, '(?<=^@\()\w+', 'match', 'once');` instead. But this seems to be only a matter of taste.